# Azure Pipelines - Deployment Environment - tags

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am using Azure Pipeline Environments to help me to align the Azure Pipeline Agent servers.

I have 2 agents running on the same vm, running under separate accounts, for security reasons.

I sometimes have a script that I want to run for one set of accounts, so I have added tags for Build and Release.

[The example / information page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops) talks about using tags against a deployment stragegy with environment and vm resources, but only a mention of how they are a string and a "List of Filters", but not really any examples of how this all works.

```
environment:
    name: string # Name of environment.
    resourceName: string # Name of resource.
    resourceId: string # Id of resource.
    resourceType: string # Type of environment resource.
    tags: string # List of tag filters.
```

I am using an extended template so that I can reuse the deployment strategy with different steps, but have extended this to allow me to change the environment and tag, so I can use it in loads of places.

```
parameters:
- name: deployment # the name of the parameter
  type: string # data type
  default: "align" # default value
- name: ENV
  type: string
  default: "AGT" #default value
- name: tags # the name of the parameter
  type: string
  default: "Build" # default value
- name: buildSteps # the name of the parameter is buildSteps
  type: stepList # data type is StepList
  default: [] # default value of buildSteps

- deployment: ${{ parameters.deployment }}
  environment: 
    name: ${{ parameters.ENV }}
    resourceType: VirtualMachine
    tags: ${{ parameters.tags }}
  strategy: 
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - ${{ each step in parameters.buildSteps }}:
          - ${{ each pair in step }}:
              ${{ if ne(pair.value, 'CmdLine@2') }}:
                ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}       
              ${{ if eq(pair.value, 'CmdLine@2') }}: 
                # Step is rejected by raising a YAML syntax error: Unexpected value 'CmdLine@2'
                '${{ pair.value }}': error
```

At the moment I have the code repeated twice to pass in different tags, but would like to call it once.

Im trying to find how you might pass in 2 tags or how would you set no tag to effectively ignore the tags (would null work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some additional detail on how tags can be used with virtual machines within an Azure Pipeline Environment:

- Within an *Environment*, you can add multiple Virtual Machine resources and each machine can be assigned zero or more tags.
- The [YAML schema for environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-deployment-environment?view=azure-pipelines#examples-1) describes the `tags` property as a comma-delimited string.
- You can use the `resourceName` property of the deployment to target a specific virtual machine resource.

  ```yaml
  - deployment: deploy
    environment:
      name: MyEnvironment
      resourceType: virtualMachine
      resourceName: MyVM
  ```
- Or you can target one or more machines based on the tags they support as outlined in this [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments-virtual-machines?view=azure-devops#add-and-manage-tags). The referenced example targets all virtual machines in an environment that have both the 'windows' and 'prod' tag:

  ```yaml
  - deployment : deploy
    environment:
      name: MyEnvironment
      resourceType: virtualMachine
      tags: windows,prod
  ```

Based on the above, if you're looking to deploy to both machines, you could exclude the tags using a simple conditional insertion statement:

```yaml
- deployment: ${{ parameters.deployment }}
  environment: 
    name: ${{ parameters.ENV }}
    resourceType: VirtualMachine
    ${{ if ne( parameters.tags, '') }}:
      tags: ${{ parameters.tags }}
```

From a template design perspective, if you'd like to limit the tags than can be used and provide compile-time validation for the tag value, you could do the following:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: tags
  type: string
  default: 'none'
  values:
  - none
  - Build
  - Release

jobs:
- deployment: ${{ parameters.deployment }}
  environment:
    name: ${{ parameters.ENV }}
    resourceType: virtualMachine
    ${{ if ne( parameters.tags, 'none') }}:
     tags: ${{ parameters.tags }}
```

Comment: That is a very compressive answer thank you.

Comment: DevOps is for everyone! A rising tide raises all ships.

Comment: Are the tags "and" clauses? So if I say `tags: windows,prod`, the resource would need both tags?

Comment: The document suggests this. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: I think i missed that, that is what i am seeing. I was hoping that the tags were inclusive, but i can see why filtering out on tags works as well. Just flipped the code a bit and it works. I only have the 2 tags in the environment, i guess i can always add more tags for different filters to work